# How can i getting data from the form correctly

Tags: java, html, forms, post, thymeleaf

For example, I have the entity User

What class i should use in the data-th-object for good practice:
it should be User or maybe RegistrationForm or UserDTO what is the best solution for take data from form?

```
<form method=POST data-th-object=${what is good practice for use there} data-th-action=@{/registration}>
   //some data
</form>
```

Comment: It is a good idea to add an empty User object into model before returning the template. Subsequently, you can use `th:object="${user}"` in your form, and in the input fields you can use `th:field="*{name}"`

Comment: Minor note, based on the comment from @prebiusta: using `data-th-object=` is equivalent to using `th:object=`. Both are valid in Thymeleaf. The first syntax is also HTML5 valid (whereas the second one is not).

Comment: All your attributes seem to be missing quotation. While it's true you can omit them if the attribute value is of a [very specific form](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values), just be in the habit of always using them so you don't run into bugs caused by forgetting when you should, and when you're allowed not to, quote your attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like to use dedicated form data objects, and not the entities themselves in forms, to have a clearer separation of concerns. I explain this in more detail at https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/